# jQuery - Margin left minus half of the div's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to achieve something like this:

I have a div, which width is not specified, so it changes basing on the content it has. First of all, I want to calculate that div's width. After that, I would like to add css style with jquery, which will margin that div left half of its width. So, if the div's width is 300px, I want this css added to the same div:

```
margin-left: -150px;
```

I hope I was clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `margin-left: -50%;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
// get div width
var width = $('div').width();

// calculate margin size
var marginLeft = width / 2;

// set css
$('div').css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
```

Comment: I added a - (minus) before marginLeft at the last line, and it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var w = $("#left-shunted-div").width();
var left_mar = -(w/2);
$("#left-shunted-div").css("margin-left",left_mar);
```

Comment: you should parseInt(value, radix) cause `.css` will return a string with `px`, not a Number

Comment: In my experience, javascript has no problem concantenating strings and integers.

Comment: *"In my experience, javascript has no problem concantenating strings and integers."* http://jsbin.com/umiruf/3/edit Well... your experience should also take good suggestions in consideration.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on that. I actually misunderstood your comment at first, thought you were criticizing a different issue.

Comment: Well than please edit your answer by using `.width()` (which will return a Number) and you don't need `w/2+"px";` just `w/2;` Actually you don't need that `var` at all, just `$("#left-shunted-div").css({marginLeft: w/2});`

Comment: @RokoC You didn't want to just suggest an edit? In any case I like the extra line with the `var`; it makes the code a little more legible to beginners like me.

Comment: Thanks for having patience with me!

Comment: :) a minus in `-left_mar` would be perfect

Comment: added the minus sign in the line above. Makes more sense to me there.

Comment: altho you don't need the `()` just `-w/2` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it like so:

```
// After dom load
$(function(){
    // Select the div
    var div = $('#myDiv');
    // Get the width;
    var width = div.outerWidth();
    // Change the margin-left to half negative 
    div.css({'marginLeft' : -(width / 2) + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: you don't need `+'px'`